# How can I add bold text and AccessText to a Label or TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF conundrum. I want some text to look like this:

> Enter this **preparer's** info:
>   [ComboBox]

Alt+E is the access key that focuses the ComboBox, and when Alt is pressed, the E in the text should be underlined.

I can get the access key to work easily:

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=PreparerComboBox}">
    _Enter this preparer's info:</Label>
```

But then "preparer's" can't be bold because a Label doesn't support Runs (as far as I can tell).

I can do the bolding easily in a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock>Enter this <Bold>preparer's</Bold> info:</TextBlock>
```

But there's no access key defined, so I tried adding my AccessText inside the TextBlock:

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=PreparerComboBox}">
    <TextBlock>
        <AccessText>_Enter</AccessText> this <Bold>preparer's</Bold> info:
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```

But then the AccessText doesn't line up properly with the rest of the text in the TextBlock, and Margin doesn't seem to have any effect on it.

Example:
[image]

The best I've come up with so far is this *monstrosity*:

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=PreparerComboBox}">
    <WrapPanel>
        <AccessText>_E</AccessText>
        <TextBlock>nter this <Bold>preparer's</Bold> info:</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
</Label>
```

What am I missing here? Seems like there has to be an easier way.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't line up properly"? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I know it's been awhile, Kent, but I finally added a screenshot.

Comment: Did your access key show the underline under the letter? I have turned this on in Windows (to always show the mnemonic underlined) and the access key is working and setting the target's focus appropriately, but I don't see any underline under the access key's letter.

Comment: @jamiebarrow I can't remember. I've moved on somewhere else, so I don't have access to that code anymore to check.

Comment: @ElmoGallen turned out that the sizing/positioning of the label was clipping the underline, that's why I couldn't see it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't change much but how about

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=PreparerComboBox}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <AccessText>_Enter</AccessText>
        <TextBlock xml:space="preserve"> this <Bold>preparer's</Bold> info:</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Label>
```

Comment: This is better. xml:space="preserve" is nice, but overall this is almost exactly like my monstrosity above.